# Tag AWS sub-accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags

guys is there any way to tag all aws sub-accounts programmatically? Been playing with tag editor but it is only helpful with the resources, looking to tag almost 20 sub-accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a boto3 client for AWS organizations.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#client

Comment: Thank you! it is helpful